# Can't paint on directly on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, paint

I have an assignment to create a paint program in Java. I have managed to create something but not exactly what I wanted.

My problem is that I cannot create a JFrame in my IDE(NetBeans 7.0.1) from the options that the IDE gives me, and call the paint classes correctly.

To be more specific I want to press a button from one panel(ex. Panel1) and paint in Panel2,in the same frame.

That's the calling of the class:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    PaintFlower102 f = new PaintFlower102();
}
```

Part of Class:

```
    super("Drag to Paint");
    getContentPane().add(new Label ("Click and Drag"),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    // add(new JButton("Brush 20"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    addMouseMotionListener( new MouseMotionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            xval=event.getX();
            yval=event.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    });

    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(PaintFlower102.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {      
    g.fillOval(xval, yval, 10, 10);   
}
```

The problem is that if I do not put the `extend JFrame` in the class this doesn't work. And if I do, it creates a new frame in which I can draw.

Comment: Assignment like homework? Please add more code, this is quite unsufficient to allow for any reasonable advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Don't ever paint directly in a JFrame except under rare circumstances of absolute need (this isn't one of them).
- Instead paint in a JPanel or JComponent or other derivative of JComponent.
- Paint in the class's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, not in `paint(Graphics g)`.
- Read the Java tutorials on this as it's all explained well there. Check out [Trail: 2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But if I dont have to paint in a JFrame and instead on a JPanel,when i create the JFrame and the panel from IDE how will i call the paint method from the panel.
I hope u understand my question.
For example,if I pressed a button ,I should add an eventlistener calling the method?

Comment: @Leonidas: You never call paint or paintcomponent methods directly. Instead you create the method overrides and call `repaint()` if you want them called. Also, there are ways to tell the IDE that you want to override a method of the super class, and this is what you should do. Myself, I don't use NetBeans but rather code my Swing GUI's by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think that you need to include super.paintComponent(g), and override the paintComponent method like Hovercraft Full Of Eels said.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);       

    // Draw Oval
   g.fillOval(xval, yval, 10, 10);
}
```