# why paint method not being called in snake game

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, paintcomponent, repaint

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        System.out.println("In here...");
        g.drawRect(frame.getWidth()/2,frame.getHeight()/2,(frame.getWidth()/2)+5,(frame.getHeight()/2+5));
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(frame.getWidth()/2,frame.getHeight()/2,(frame.getWidth()/2)+5,(frame.getHeight()/2+5));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        if(ae.getSource() == slow)
        {
            this.setMotionToSnake(slowMotion);  
            this.repaint();
        }

}
}
```

Im writing a snake game program. While doing that paint method is not being called. 
Explaining the code: 
im adding one menu bar to my frame 
in that menu bar start is one menu with 3 sub menus in it viz slow,medium,fast.
Whenever i say slow the motion of the snake to move is decided and now i should able to see a rectangular box(at least) in the frame.
Thats why im calling the repaint method there.

Other than this.repaint() i have also used frame.repaint() / just repaint().
But method is not getting invoked.

Thanks for ur help in advanced.

Comment: Also for reference ---> im using flow layout manager
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

Comment: [Searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jframe+paint+not+called) before posting could help, for example there is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301380/cant-paint-on-directly-on-jframe).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) `public void paint(Graphics g) { super.paint(g);` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g);`

Answer (score 1):

> im using flow layout manager frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

A FlowLayout respects the size of all the components added to the panel. You are creating a custom component and by default the size of your component is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Override the `getPreferredSize()` of your custom component to return the proper Dimension for your component.

Also, custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method, not the paint() method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples that show how to do this.